# Fetching keys from Redis

Tags: java, redis

Is there a possibility of fetching n number of keys at a time in Redis?

I have more than a million keys in a Redis and I want to prepare a csv file of 100k records each. I want to fetch 100k keys and prepare the files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can use `SCAN` command with `COUNT` option.** ([link](https://redis.io/commands/scan))

The following code sample uses [jedis](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis) as the redis client.

```
    // Assuming redis is running on port 32768 on localhost
    // insert some records
    Jedis jedis = new Jedis("localhost", 32768);
    jedis.set("foo1", "bar1");
    jedis.set("foo2", "bar2");
    jedis.set("foo3", "bar3");
    jedis.set("foo4", "bar4");
    jedis.set("foo5", "bar5");

    // first value of cursor must be "0"
    String cursor = "0";

    // fetch 2 keys in every scan
    ScanParams scanParams = new ScanParams().count(2);

    do {
        ScanResult<String> scanResult = jedis.scan(cursor, scanParams);

        System.out.println("Keys for cursor ---> " + cursor);
        scanResult.getResult().forEach((key) -> {
            System.out.println("Key = " + key);
        });

        cursor = scanResult.getCursor();
    } while (!"0".equals(cursor));
```

Here I am fetching 2 keys in every iteration of the scan command. The cursor value returned in the `ScanResult` is sent as input to the next scan command. If there are no more results, cursor value is "0". This is used for signalling the termination of the for loop.

I saw the following output on running this sample.

```
Keys for cursor ---> 0
Key == foo1
Key == foo3
Keys for cursor ---> 4
Key == foo2
Key == foo
Keys for cursor ---> 1
Key == foo5
Key == foo4
Keys for cursor ---> 5
```

Comment: Great..that helps..i just have another question...what happens if the same time some keys are added or removed..that will create a mismatch in getting all the keys..

Comment: Yes, that is a problem that needs to be solved at application level. This is also mentioned in the docs as `Elements that were not constantly present in the collection during a full iteration, may be returned or not: it is undefined.`

Comment: As per the docs it is mentioned that it is possible that some of the keys get missed also. Is it possible?

Comment: Redis guarantees that if your key is present in the database during the full iteration it will be returned. However, if a key is deleted during the iteration it may or may not be returned.

Comment: To guard against missing keys due to deletion during the iteration, a listener can be subscribed to the delete event. Like described [here](https://redis.io/topics/notifications)

Answer (score 1):

Use `RedisTemplate`, By using a `keys` method you can get all keys in a Redis like below:

Spring doc : [RedisTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/RedisTemplate.html)

```
Set<String> allAvailableKeys = redisTemplate.keys("*"));
Iterator<String> iterator = allAvailableKeys.iterator();
List<String> allAvailableKeyList = new ArrayList<>();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
       String key= iterator.next();
       allAvailableKeyList.add(key);
}
```

Using Java8 :

```
Set<String> allAvailableKeys = redisTemplate.keys("*"));
List<String> allAvailableKeyList =allAvailableKeys.stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I don't want to fetch all the keys at once...i want to fetch partly..like 1 Lakh into one list and then onwards..